# Structure allocated but not assigned

Tags: c++, c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a BST in C/C++.

Note: In this class, submissions are expected to have a `.cpp` file extension and should compile with a C++ compiler, but should be "philosophically" C (`printf()`, `malloc()`, etc.), with certain C++ features allowed (native `bool`s, etc.). This also means working around C++ restrictions (casting the result of `malloc()`, adding `const` to strings, etc.). The line is fuzzy, so to be safe I am doing it C style - this is a personal project that I hope to be able to recycle when needed by simply adapting a few key functions.

I have a function `pushBST()` that calls `pushBSTNode()`:

```cpp
bool pushBST(BST* tree, const char* val_cstr, int val_int) {
    if (tree == NULL) return false;

    BSTData* data = createBSTData(val_cstr, val_int);
    if (data == NULL) return false;
    return pushBSTNode(tree->root, tree->root, data);
}
```

```cpp
bool pushBSTNode(BSTNode* node, BSTNode* parent, BSTData* data) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        node = createBSTNode(data, parent);
        if (node == NULL) return false;
        return true;
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

My idea here is to abstract away pushing data to the BST with `pushBST()`, requiring only the tree itself and the raw data. However, this doesn't work, despite returning true. A peek into it with GDB in VSCode tells me that something is up, but I can't quite understand it.

Calling the function works as expected initially:

```cpp
if (tree == NULL) return false; // So it doesn't choke on a void pointer, passed

BSTData* data = createBSTData(...); // It packed the data correctly, passed
if (data == NULL) return false; // Report a failure if the data failed to pack, passed.
```

At this point, I can see the variables are correct: the tree exists and the data is packed with the correct values. Following it is the function to actually push it:

```cpp
if (node == NULL) { // tree->root was indeed NULL, passed
    node = createBSTNode(...); // This allocates a node and assigns it the packed data, passed
    if (node == NULL) return false; // The node exists, passed
    return true; // Therefore, this should have worked
}
```

The `node` that was passed in refers to `tree->root`, so it should have allocated a node structure there. At the end of that function, it is indeed true that the `node` variable has the data and the data is correct (the variable `parent` is wrong, but I'm going to work on it later). However, upon returning to the main push function, I see the variable hasn't changed. The variable `tree->root` is still `NULL`, but now it has a return value, indicating a supposed success.

Any ideas on what went wrong and how I can fix it?

---

Here is the test program I use:

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#include "bstree.hpp"

int main() {
    myds::bst::BST* tree = myds::bst::createBST();
    myds::bst::pushBST(tree, "yeet val 1", 5);
    myds::bst::pushBST(tree, "yeet val 2", 3);
    myds::bst::pushBST(tree, "yeet val 3", 4);
    myds::bst::pushBST(tree, "yeet val 4", 1);
    myds::bst::pushBST(tree, "yeet val 5", 2);
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

`bstree.hpp`:

```cpp
#ifndef BSTREE_HPP
#define BSTREE_HPP

#include <stddef.h>

namespace myds::bst {
    struct BSTData {
        char val_cstr[16];
        int val_int
    };

    struct BSTNode {
        BSTData* data;

        BSTNode* parent;
        BSTNode* left;
        BSTNode* right;
    };

    struct BST {
        BSTNode* root;
    };

    BSTData* createBSTData(const char* val_cstr, int val_int);
    BSTNode* createBSTNode(BSTData* data, BSTNode* parent);
    BST* createBST();

    bool pushBSTNode(BSTNode* node, BSTNode* parent, BSTData* data);
    bool pushBST(BST* tree, const char* val_cstr, int val_int);
}

#endif
```

`bstree.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "bstree.hpp"

namespace myds::bst {
    BSTData* createBSTData(const char* val_cstr, int val_int) {
        BSTData* data = (BSTData*) malloc(sizeof(BSTData));
        if (data == NULL) return NULL;

        strcpy(data->val_cstr, val_cstr);
        data->val_int = val_int;

        return data;
    }

    BSTNode* createBSTNode(BSTData* data, BSTNode* parent) {
        BSTNode* node = (BSTNode*) malloc(sizeof(BSTNode));
        if (node == NULL) return NULL;

        node->data = data;

        node->parent = parent;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;

        return node;
    }

    BST* createBST() {
        BST* tree = (BST*) malloc(sizeof(BST));
        if (tree == NULL) return NULL;

        tree->root = NULL;

        return tree;
    }

    bool pushBSTNode(BSTNode* node, BSTNode* parent, BSTData* data) {
        if (node == NULL) {
            node = createBSTNode(data, parent);
            if (node == NULL) return false;
            return true;
        } else {
            ssize_t delta = compareBSTData(data, node->data);
            if (delta < 0) {
                // data is smaller than current node, should go to left side of node
                return pushBSTNode(node->left, node, data);
            } else if (delta == 0) {
                // data == node, cannot store duplicate values
                return false;
            } else if (delta > 1) {
            // data is larger than current node, should go to the right side of node
                return pushBSTNode(node->right, node, data);
            }
        }

        return false; // silence clang
    }

    bool pushBST(BST* tree, const char* val_cstr, int val_int) {
        if (tree == NULL) return false;

        BSTData* data = createBSTData(val_cstr, val_int);
        if (data == NULL) return false;
        bool retval = pushBSTNode(tree->root, tree->root, data);
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Comment: To be safe you should NOT write in C style, that is a bad habit a lead to a lot of anti-pattern

Comment: @Moia Yes, I wouldn't write a C style cast in a full C++ program, but the requirements of my class to write "philosophically C code that compiles with a C++ compiler and more resitrictions" basically means bad C++ code (structs and functions to deal with them).

Comment: Well then, the most important things is be well aware of that

Comment: Try `bool pushBSTNode(BSTNode*& node, BSTNode*& parent, BSTData* data)` instead. The pointers are currently being passed by value, so you can change them insude the functions but that change won't affect the original pointers that were passed in.

Comment: The shown code does not meet Stackoverflow's requirements for a [mre]. This means that nobody can cut/paste it, ***exactly as shown***, compile, and observe the same results. Until it does so, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you anything useful.

Comment: You apparently want to assign some value to a pointer that is defined outside in a function. Then, don't hand in the pointer, but rather a pointer to it.

Comment: @tofro Passing a reference is safer (no need to check for null) and easier to understand wherever possible.

Comment: having completely different behaviour when NULL is passed for one argument is an antipattern as well. It'd be better to have two separate functions with different names that indicate their use

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have provided my work so far, please let me know if I need to include anything else.

Comment: @M.M The check for NULL (I'm assuming you're talking about the check in `pushBSTNode()` is to guard in case the missing root, where the tree was newly created and does not have any nodes yet. This allows the calling code to keep pushing, without needing to worry whether the tree has its first node yet, whether to immediately create a node or traversing the tree first. I think this is a fair use of the check (then again the class is teaching data structures, not best practices).

Comment: @underscore_d That's not "C-style"

Comment: @tofro big shrug. "certain C++ features allowed" is vague enough that I can say it if I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers used for propagation of the tree need to be passed by reference. If you pass by value (without reference), any changes made within the scope of your CreateBSTNode function are lost when the function is complete.

```
pushBSTNode(BSTNode* &node, BSTNode* &parent, BSTData* &data)
```

Comment: Not "any" pointers, just ones that the function needs to update and propagate outwith itself.

Comment: @underscore_d, that's right. Thank you. Updating now.

Comment: even if that's better C++, it's definitely not conforming with the C style requirement as in the question (whatever that's good for)

Comment: @tofro yeah, I’m not a fan of the implementation at all, but this is a way to get the desired output without rewiriting the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you, it appears I've missed that. References are nicer than pointers, but likely not acceptable, so I've changed them for double pointers. I'll ask anyway if references are allowed.